# One type argument expected for class Result<out T> error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

List<Result, from what I know, is supposed to be on the same package. But I tried to separate codes like HomeActivity, HomeAdapter, and HomeView for List to create more directive program. As a result, I got an error of One type argument expected for class Result. I tried to add import direction to make sure it is connected, but it doesn't work. The problem also lies to HomeResponse, which I tried to refactor automatically, but it won't work, saying it cannot set package name for compiled files, so I need to do it manually. And it became regular file, look for picture 'Kotlin Path'. I need your shares for this problem.

HomeAdapter.kt:

```
package id.kotlin.belajar.presentation

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import id.kotlin.belajar.R
import id.kotlin.belajar.data.HomeResponse


class HomeAdapter (private val results: List<Result>): RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder>(){

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeViewHolder {
    return HomeViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater
            .from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_home,
                parent,
                false
            )
    )
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HomeViewHolder, position: Int){
    holder.bind(results[holder.adapterPosition])
}
override fun getItemCount(): Int{
    return results.count()
}

inner class HomeViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    fun bind(result: Result){
        with(itemView) {
            val name = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.original_title)
            name.text = result.title

            val country = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.overview)
            country.text = result.overview
        }
    }

  }
}
```

HomeActivity.kt:

```
class HomeActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), HomeView {
@Inject
lateinit var presenter: HomePresenter

private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pb_home)
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_home)

    presenter.discoverMovie()
}

override fun onShowLoading() {
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
override fun onHideLoading() {
    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    recyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

override fun onResponse(results: List<Result>) {
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this@HomeActivity, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
    recyclerView.adapter = HomeAdapter(results)
}

override fun onFailure(t:Throwable) {
    Log.e(HomeActivity::class.java.simpleName, "${t.printStackTrace()}")
 }
}
```

HomeView.kt:

```
interface HomeView {
    fun onShowLoading()
    fun onHideLoading()
    fun onResponse(results: List<Result>)
    fun onFailure(t: Throwable)
}
```

For kotlin path project:
[Java path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Sfq.png)

Comment: Please add the **Result** class.

Comment: What kind of the Result class will be?

Comment: After seeing the code, I am assuming that you have defined a class named **Result** which contains **overview** and **title** as variables. I am asking for the same part of the code.

Comment: I have deleted the second same variables. And the error is gone. I hope it worked out

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
class HomeAdapter (private val results: List<Result<Any>>): RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder>(){
```

to `<Any>` remove

```
class HomeAdapter (private val results: List<Result>): RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder>(){
```

Comment: where is Result class

Comment: Because if I delete any, 'One type argument expected for class Result<out T>' error comes out,

Comment: send me error and code